# File directory constantly changing Perl

Tags: perl

I want to retrieve number of lines from `data.list` in this directory : `Project/chris/company/Delta/force/run_20210619_df/total/data.list` But the problem is the `run_20210619_df` changes and is replaced everytime a new data is updated into data.list.

lets say original directory was : `Project/chris/company/Delta/force/run_20210619_df/total/data.list`

but today the `data.list` is being updated, so a new directory is formed : `Project/chris/company/Delta/force/run_20210624_df/total/data.list`

and both the directory contains `data.list`

can i make a script that can always read **the LATEST version of** `data.list`?

`Delta and charlie` are different directory to retrieve the data.list as there are many datal.list to retrieve from

**Based on someone's answer i got this :**

```
my $filepathABC = Project/chris/company/Delta/force/*/total/data.list
my $filepathBCD = Project/chris/company/Charlie/force/*/total/data.list
my $hashref;
my $path;

print "Enter path : ";
$path = <STDIN>;
chomp $path;

  if ( $path eq "ABC" ) {
     for my $file ( glob($filepathABC ) ) {
     $hashref->{$file} = count_lines($file);
     $curl and upload data here........
     }
  else ($path eq "BCD") {
     for my $file ( glob($filepathBCD ) ) {
     $hashref->{$file} = count_lines($file);
     $curl and upload data here........
     }

sub count_lines {
my $fname = shift;
my $count;
open my $fh, '<', $fname or die $!;
$count = grep { not ?^$|^\s*#/ }<$fh>;
close $fh;
printf "$count\n";
return $count;
}
```

Unfortunately, when i run the script, it cant detect which data.list to pull info from.

Comment: Your question is missing important details, so no one can answer it usefully. But look at the the perl package `File::Find`. It might be helpful.

Comment: @Gene maybe now its clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's question is not clear if a directory `run_20210619_df` substituted with a new directory on each update of `data.list` file or there will be multiple directories at this level of filesystem.

Please investigate following demo code snippet which looks for `data.list` in file structure with `*` as a wildcard in place of `run_20210619_df` directory.

A simple subroutine `count_lines($fname)` is implemented to count lines in a file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $files = 'Project/chris/company/Delta/force/*/total/data.list';
my $hashref;

for my $file ( glob($files) ) {
    $hashref->{$file} = count_lines($file);
}

say Dumper($hashref);

sub count_lines {
    my $fname = shift;
    my $count;

    open my $fh, '<', $fname or die $!;
    $count++ while <$fh>;
    close $fh;

    return $count;
}
```

Per OP's request: change code to print only number of lines

```
for my $file ( glob($files) ) {
    say count_lines($file);
}
```

Updated version:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $files = './Project/chris/company/*/force/*/total/data.list';
my $hashref;

for my $file ( glob($files) ) {
    my($id,$date) = (split('/',$_))[4,6];
    if( $hashref->{$id) and $date gt $hashref->{$id}{date} ) {
        $hashref->{$id}{file}   = $file;
        $hashref->{$id}{date}   = $date;
        $hashref->{$id}{count}  = count_lines($file);
    } else {
        $hashref->{$id}{file}   = $file;
        $hashref->{$id}{date}   = $date;
        $hashref->{$id}{count}  = count_lines($file);
    }
}

say Dumper($hashref);

sub count_lines {
    my $fname = shift;
    my $count;

    open my $fh, '<', $fname or die $!;
    $count++ while <$fh>;
    close $fh;

    return $count;
}
```

*Description:*
Updated code relies on components of the path to extract `Delta`,`Charlie`, etc. as an `$id` and `date_df` as a reference date string `$date`.

Then we build hash of hashes to separate information for each `$id` which will hold a filename, date_df string and count of file lines.

The comparison of extracted `$date` with stored `$hashref->{$id}{date}`  achieved with string comparison operator `gt` and if new date more resent then an update of hash information takes place.

Once all files are processed the final result stored in a hash referenced with `$hashref` can be utilized to upload information of interest.

Test script to see if any file found (if `$files` points to correct location).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $files = './Project/chris/company/*/force/*/total/data.list';

for my $file ( glob($files) ) {
    say $file;
}
```

Test script

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $files = './*/*/*.pl';

while( glob($files) ) {
    say;
}
```

Output

```
./kodi/bin/category.pl
./perl/capacitor/capacitor.pl
./perl/db/test.pl
./perl/db/x_test.pl
./perl/examples/abc.pl
./perl/examples/abcd.pl
./perl/examples/ampl.pl
./perl/examples/arr_cc.pl
./perl/examples/arr_dup.pl
......
./perl/YouTube/test_channel.pl
./perl/YouTube/test_playlist.pl
./perl/YouTube/test_playlists.pl
./perl/YouTube/test_search.pl
./perl/YouTube/test_videos.pl
./php/x/map_file.pl
```

Reference:
[glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob)

Comment: hi mr bear, yes, a directory run_20210619_df it will be substitute away

Comment: If it is so, then in hash you will have only one pair (key - filename and value - lines count).

Comment: hey mr polar bear, can you edit it in such a way, it only prints out the number of lines? Instead of the whole chunk of "PWD" as this is quite advance for me ! thanks !

Comment: @HelpMeAndroidStudio -- please inspect a small change in the code I've added per your request, `say Dumper($hashref);` should be removed as it will not be needed any more.

Comment: I've tried since yesterday to implement ur code into the if else, but dosnt seem to work. any advice?

Comment: Open new ticket with your code and provide a description what problem you experience.
[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: its the same question that i've being asking, how to implement it into the if else loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234093/discussion-between-helpmeandroidstudio-and-polar-bear).

Comment: @bear hi, i just confirm that directory run_20210619_df will generate a new folder everytime it update the data.list. any idea how to code ?

Comment: What is `Delta` and `Charlie`?

Comment: i updated the question. sorry for the confusion

Comment: maybe u can answer here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/655243/file-directory-constantly-changing-perl

Comment: So, in place of `Delta` and `Charlie` can be other _directory names_? When in your question you refer latest `data.list` you mean that under for `Delta` you can have many `run_20210619_df ` directories and you interested in most recent?

Comment: yessir ! thats what i meant ! exactly ! sorry for my bad english, i have many run_20210618_df, but it create a new directory everytime it runs, based on the date

Comment: Finally some useful information to understand what is your goal. Now it looks like you need create a hash with a key as `Delta`,`Charlie`, etc. and then for each of them you need to find the latest `data.list` file. An with this information at hand count number of lines for these files. Is it correct?

Comment: Ok, now I see that you has path in the variable relative to some start point -- due this reason we need start from current directory `.`.

Comment: Ok, try to run new code -- it should produce desired hash which you could utilize to upload files of interest.

Comment: thanksss ! care to comment and let me know whats what? if u are free? meanwhile let me try it

Comment: hi ,sorry it dosnt seem to work. i've double check the codes. and the delta/charlie aside, i cant even read the data.list file from ur original script which u help me yesterday

Comment: Did `say Dump($hashref)` produced correct output for latest file for each of `Delta`,`Charlie`, etc? If it is then you should read filename from `$hashref->{$id}{file}` and number of lines from `$hashref->{$id}{count}` where `$id` is one of `Delta`,`Charlie`, etc.

Comment: no it says cant find the path. coz the actual path is different from what i wrote here, but i change it accordingly. is it because i cant read the directory from server

Comment: Ok, I did a little change to `$files` to include `./` at begin of it. You should run this script from a directory where `Project` directory located. Or you have to specify fully qualified path starting from root of filesystem (`/`).

Comment: I've added perl your request description for updated code.

Comment: It keeps prompting me, wrong path / directory. i dont get it. i am running the script from my project account using $caja.

Comment: What OS are you in?

Comment: i am using linux, u want to chat in discussion room so we dont spam here?

Comment: Are you behind firewall? Do you know how to use [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/download/linux/)? I could look at what you have and if you permit to control your computer I could _modify_ the code to match your filesystem.

Comment: Yes , i cant share screen as i am using company stuff. but, lets backtrack abit, can we start from trying to find the latest updated data.list ? wihtout looking at the delta / charlie thing. as i can just hardcode it next time using IF ELSE

Comment: Then comment lines where program count lines and post under your question output from `Dumper`. At least we will see what happening there.

Comment: it returns SVAR = undef
i tried to breakdown to solve. i realise that the script cant bring me to the desired directory

Comment: Well, it indicates that your variable `$files` point to none existing location -- it would explain why you get `undef` and there is nothing to process at all. Try to print in `for my $file ...`  next command `say $file;` to confirm that no files found at location you point to through `$files` variable.

Comment: how can i do that? can u edit the code? sorry

Comment: when i print "$files";
 , it gives me `Project/chris/company/Delta/force/*/total/data.list` . it wont show whats * i assume ?

Comment: See a small script for this purpose added to very end of my answer.

Comment: You can try `ls Project/chris/company/*/force/*/total/data.list` to see if  [ls](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) command will produce any output and if you have correct location to run the script.

Comment: Using the ls, it returns me 6 of them as i have 6 different * , but it means i can access that directory

Comment: i think what i need now is only extracting the latest * in terms of $date rather than the delta/charlie

Comment: Well, see my simple test script I run on my remote server which produces list of perl files two directory levels down in filesystem. Not sure what you do with the script in your case.

Comment: it does return me  all the files with the name data.list when i run ur test script. but when i try to count it using the `sub count_lines`, it dosnt return anything

Comment: You must search assistance from your supervisor.

Comment: last thing, can you edit ur codes , so that i only take into account of changes of date, taking it as charlie and delta have no change and its always charlie

Comment: No, you should ask for help from your supervisor.

Comment: well sadly, if there is someone to ask i wont be asking questions here. thanks